# What is the meaning of "Is that so?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'd like to know what is the real meaning of this expression: Is that so?

In the text where this expression was, There was an ask denied before this phrase

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It usually follows someone's assertion that a particular fact is true or a particular has happened, and it asks "Is that true?" or "Is that the case?" It may be uttered either as a genuine request for confirmation ...

> **A:** I've just found out that Prof. Sartorius is going to be our next department chair.
>   **B:** Is that so? That's very interesting; everybody thought Dr. Trench was going to get the job.

... or as a sarcastic or belligerent challenge ...

> **A:** I've just found out that Prof. Sartorius is going to be our next department chair.
>   **B:** Is that so?! I've got twenty bucks to a dime says you're full of it.

Since you say the prompt was the denial of a request, it is likely that the second sense was intended:

> **A:** I'm afraid the Committee has decided not to fund your proposal.
>   **B:** Is that so? Well, there's lots of corporations out there that would be happy to give me the big bucks.

"Oh, yes/yeah?" has much the same meaning and range of applications.

Comment: Thanks so much! As you said I think the author used in a sarcastic way